# Collect doesn't work properly

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I run Want to write an expression in the form of

```
expr= (b rr^w+ q rr^v +...)/(c rr^n + p rr^m + d rr^s +...)
```

To do that, I write

```
Collect[expr,rr]
```

But the output is in the form:

```
(k rr^e (kk +u rr^c+..)+...)/(A rr^t)+o rr^d
```

The problem is this kind of terms `(k rr^e (kk +u rr^c+..))` which MM doesn't write them as `(k kk rr^e + k u rr^(c+e))`.

Could any one help me? `expr` is presented [here](https://files.fm/u/48qe92dc#_).
I have also provided a simpler form for `expr` which has the same problem when using collect. It is shorter comparing to the above link.

```
expr=(-h Cos[t] (-(1/(
        12 a eta g h (g + h) \[Pi]))(-2 g h (g + h) + 
           3 a (g^2 + g h + h^2)) H Cos[t] Cos[
          tp] (-((g H^2 rr^3 Cos[
              tp] (15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] - 
               2 Cos[tp] + 
               3 (Cos[2 t + tp] + Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                  2 Cos[2 th + tp])))/(64 eta \[Pi])) + (
           g H^2 rr^3 Sin[
             tp] (-15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] + 
              2 Sin[tp] + 3 Sin[2 t + tp] - 3 Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
              6 Sin[2 th + tp]))/(64 eta \[Pi])) + (1/(
       6 a eta g \[Pi]))(-3 a + 2 g) H Cos[t] Cos[
         tp] (-((h H^2 rr^3 Cos[
             tp] (15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] - 
              2 Cos[tp] + 
              3 (Cos[2 t + tp] + Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                 2 Cos[2 th + tp])))/(64 eta \[Pi])) + (
          h H^2 rr^3 Sin[
            tp] (-15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] + 
             2 Sin[tp] + 3 Sin[2 t + tp] - 3 Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
             6 Sin[2 th + tp]))/(64 eta \[Pi]))) + 
    g Sin[t] (-(1/(
        6 a eta h \[Pi]))(3 a - 2 h) H Cos[tp] Sin[
          t] (-((g H^2 rr^3 Cos[
              tp] (15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] - 
               2 Cos[tp] + 
               3 (Cos[2 t + tp] + Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                  2 Cos[2 th + tp])))/(64 eta \[Pi])) + (
           g H^2 rr^3 Sin[
             tp] (-15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] + 
              2 Sin[tp] + 3 Sin[2 t + tp] - 3 Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
              6 Sin[2 th + tp]))/(64 eta \[Pi])) + (1/(
       12 a eta g h (g + h) \[Pi]))(2 g h (g + h) - 
          3 a (g^2 + g h + h^2)) H Cos[tp] Sin[
         t] (-((h H^2 rr^3 Cos[
             tp] (15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] - 
              2 Cos[tp] + 
              3 (Cos[2 t + tp] + Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                 2 Cos[2 th + tp])))/(64 eta \[Pi])) + (
          h H^2 rr^3 Sin[
            tp] (-15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] + 
             2 Sin[tp] + 3 Sin[2 t + tp] - 3 Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
             6 Sin[2 th + tp]))/(64 eta \[Pi])))) ((32 (3 a - 
         2 h) Cos[t] Cos[
        tp])/(3 a h^2 H rr^3 (-15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] Cos[tp] + 
         9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] Cos[tp] + 2 Cos[tp]^2 - 
         3 Cos[tp] Cos[2 t + tp] - 3 Cos[tp] Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] - 
         6 Cos[tp] Cos[2 th + tp] - 15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] Sin[tp] - 
         9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] Sin[tp] + 2 Sin[tp]^2 + 
         3 Sin[tp] Sin[2 t + tp] - 3 Sin[tp] Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
         6 Sin[tp] Sin[2 th + tp])) + (G (-(1/(
          6 a eta h \[Pi]))(3 a - 2 h) H Cos[t] Cos[
            tp] (((3 a - 
                2 H) (((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                   3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
                24 a eta H (G + 
                   H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (G + 2 H) + 
                   3 a (G^3 + G^2 H + 3 G H^2 + 2 H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
                24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi])))/(
             6 a eta \[Pi]) + (-((G (3 a - 2 H) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
                 6 a eta H \[Pi])) - ((-2 G H (G + H) + 
                   3 a (G^2 + G H + H^2)) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
                12 a eta G (G + 
                   H) \[Pi])) (((4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) - 
                   3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                  tp])/(24 a eta G (G + 
                   H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                   3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                  tp])/(24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi]))) + (1/(
         64 eta \[Pi]))
         h H^2 rr^3 Cos[
           tp] (((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
               3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(

            24 a eta H (G + H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (G + 2 H) + 
               3 a (G^3 + G^2 H + 3 G H^2 + 2 H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
            24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi])) (2 Cos[t] + 
            3 (2 Cos[t - 2 th] - 5 Cos[t - 4 th - 2 tp] - 
               Cos[t + 2 tp] - 3 Cos[t - 2 (th + tp)] + 
               Cos[t + 2 (th + tp)])) (-((
             h H^2 rr^3 Cos[
               tp] (15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 
                9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] - 2 Cos[tp] + 
                3 (Cos[2 t + tp] + Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                   2 Cos[2 th + tp])))/(64 eta \[Pi])) + (
            h H^2 rr^3 Sin[
              tp] (-15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 
               9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] + 2 Sin[tp] + 3 Sin[2 t + tp] - 
               3 Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 6 Sin[2 th + tp]))/(
            64 eta \[Pi]))))/(H ((-(((3 a - 
                2 H) (((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                   3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
                24 a eta H (G + 
                   H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (G + 2 H) + 
                   3 a (G^3 + G^2 H + 3 G H^2 + 2 H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
                24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi])))/(
             6 a eta \[Pi])) - (-((G (3 a - 2 H) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
                6 a eta H \[Pi])) - ((-2 G H (G + H) + 
                  3 a (G^2 + G H + H^2)) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
               12 a eta G (G + 
                  H) \[Pi])) (((4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) - 
                  3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                 tp])/(24 a eta G (G + 
                  H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                  3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                 tp])/(24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi]))) ((
            G h H rr^3 Cos[
              tp] (15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] - 
               2 Cos[tp] + 
               3 (Cos[2 t + tp] + Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                  2 Cos[2 th + tp])))/(64 eta \[Pi]) - (
            G h H rr^3 Sin[
              tp] (-15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 
               9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] + 2 Sin[tp] + 3 Sin[2 t + tp] - 
               3 Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 6 Sin[2 th + tp]))/(
            64 eta \[Pi])) + ((-((G (3 a - 2 H) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
                6 a eta H \[Pi])) - ((-2 G H (G + H) + 
                  3 a (G^2 + G H + H^2)) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
               12 a eta G (G + 
                  H) \[Pi])) (-(((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                   3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                  tp])/(24 a eta H (G + 
                   H) \[Pi])) + ((4 G H (G + H) (G + 2 H) - 
                  3 a (G^3 + G^2 H + 3 G H^2 + 2 H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                 tp])/(24 a eta G (G + 
                  H) \[Pi])) + (((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                  3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
               24 a eta H (G + 
                  H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (G + 2 H) + 
                  3 a (G^3 + G^2 H + 3 G H^2 + 2 H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
               24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi])) ((
               H (-(2/a) + 3/G + (3 G)/(G H + H^2)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
               12 eta \[Pi]) - (G (3 a - 2 H) Sin[tp]^2)/(
               6 a eta H \[Pi]))) (-((
             h H^2 rr^3 Cos[
               tp] (15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 
                9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] - 2 Cos[tp] + 
                3 (Cos[2 t + tp] + Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                   2 Cos[2 th + tp])))/(64 eta \[Pi])) + (
            h H^2 rr^3 Sin[
              tp] (-15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 
               9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] + 2 Sin[tp] + 3 Sin[2 t + tp] - 
               3 Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 6 Sin[2 th + tp]))/(
            64 eta \[Pi])))) + ((32 (3 a - 2 h) Cos[tp] Sin[
           t])/(3 a h^2 H rr^3 (-15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] Cos[tp] + 
            9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] Cos[tp] + 2 Cos[tp]^2 - 
            3 Cos[tp] Cos[2 t + tp] - 
            3 Cos[tp] Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] - 
            6 Cos[tp] Cos[2 th + tp] - 
            15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] Sin[tp] - 
            9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] Sin[tp] + 2 Sin[tp]^2 + 
            3 Sin[tp] Sin[2 t + tp] - 
            3 Sin[tp] Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
            6 Sin[tp] Sin[2 th + tp])) + (G (-(1/(
             6 a eta h \[Pi]))(3 a - 2 h) H Cos[tp] Sin[
               t] (((3 a - 
                   2 H) (((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                    3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
                   24 a eta H (G + 
                    H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (G + 2 H) + 
                    3 a (G^3 + G^2 H + 3 G H^2 + 2 H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
                   24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi])))/(
                6 a eta \[Pi]) + (-((G (3 a - 2 H) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
                    6 a eta H \[Pi])) - ((-2 G H (G + H) + 
                    3 a (G^2 + G H + H^2)) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
                   12 a eta G (G + 
                    H) \[Pi])) (((4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) - 
                    3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                    tp])/(24 a eta G (G + 
                    H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                    3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                    tp])/(24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi]))) + (1/(
            64 eta \[Pi]))
            h H^2 rr^3 Cos[
              tp] (((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                  3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
               24 a eta H (G + 
                  H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (G + 2 H) + 
                  3 a (G^3 + G^2 H + 3 G H^2 + 2 H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
               24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi])) (-((
                h H^2 rr^3 Cos[
                  tp] (15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 
                   9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] - 2 Cos[tp] + 
                   3 (Cos[2 t + tp] + Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                    2 Cos[2 th + tp])))/(64 eta \[Pi])) + (
               h H^2 rr^3 Sin[
                 tp] (-15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 
                  9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] + 2 Sin[tp] + 
                  3 Sin[2 t + tp] - 3 Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                  6 Sin[2 th + tp]))/(64 eta \[Pi])) (2 Sin[t] + 
               3 (-2 Sin[t - 2 th] + 5 Sin[t - 4 th - 2 tp] + 
                  Sin[t + 2 tp] - 3 Sin[t - 2 (th + tp)] + 
                  Sin[t + 2 (th + tp)]))))/(H ((-(((3 a - 
                   2 H) (((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                    3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
                   24 a eta H (G + 
                    H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (G + 2 H) + 
                    3 a (G^3 + G^2 H + 3 G H^2 + 2 H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
                   24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi])))/(
                6 a eta \[Pi])) - (-((G (3 a - 2 H) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
                   6 a eta H \[Pi])) - ((-2 G H (G + H) + 
                    3 a (G^2 + G H + H^2)) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
                  12 a eta G (G + 
                    H) \[Pi])) (((4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) - 
                    3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                    tp])/(24 a eta G (G + 
                    H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                    3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                    tp])/(24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi]))) ((
               G h H rr^3 Cos[
                 tp] (15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 
                  9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] - 2 Cos[tp] + 
                  3 (Cos[2 t + tp] + Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                    2 Cos[2 th + tp])))/(64 eta \[Pi]) - (
               G h H rr^3 Sin[
                 tp] (-15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 
                  9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] + 2 Sin[tp] + 
                  3 Sin[2 t + tp] - 3 Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                  6 Sin[2 th + tp]))/(
               64 eta \[Pi])) + ((-((G (3 a - 2 H) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
                   6 a eta H \[Pi])) - ((-2 G H (G + H) + 
                    3 a (G^2 + G H + H^2)) Cos[tp] Sin[tp])/(
                  12 a eta G (G + 
                    H) \[Pi])) (-(((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                    3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                    tp])/(24 a eta H (G + 
                    H) \[Pi])) + ((4 G H (G + H) (G + 2 H) - 
                    3 a (G^3 + G^2 H + 3 G H^2 + 2 H^3)) Cos[tp] Sin[
                    tp])/(24 a eta G (G + 
                    H) \[Pi])) + (((-4 G H (G + H) (2 G + H) + 
                    3 a (2 G^3 + 3 G^2 H + G H^2 + H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
                  24 a eta H (G + 
                    H) \[Pi]) + ((-4 G H (G + H) (G + 2 H) + 
                    3 a (G^3 + G^2 H + 3 G H^2 + 2 H^3)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
                  24 a eta G (G + H) \[Pi])) ((
                  H (-(2/a) + 3/G + (3 G)/(G H + H^2)) Cos[tp]^2)/(
                  12 eta \[Pi]) - (G (3 a - 2 H) Sin[tp]^2)/(
                  6 a eta H \[Pi]))) (-((
                h H^2 rr^3 Cos[
                  tp] (15 Cos[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 
                   9 Cos[2 t - 2 th - tp] - 2 Cos[tp] + 
                   3 (Cos[2 t + tp] + Cos[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                    2 Cos[2 th + tp])))/(64 eta \[Pi])) + (
               h H^2 rr^3 Sin[
                 tp] (-15 Sin[2 t - 4 th - tp] - 
                  9 Sin[2 t - 2 th - tp] + 2 Sin[tp] + 
                  3 Sin[2 t + tp] - 3 Sin[2 t - 2 th + tp] + 
                  6 Sin[2 th + tp]))/(64 eta \[Pi]))))) Tan[t]);
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete, self-contained example small enough to fit in this post?

Comment: Sorry, no. I can not do that because I don't know where does the problem originate from @Mr.Wizard

Comment: I did find a simpler example and put it in the question @Mr.Wizard

Comment: Is it ok or I should find smpler example? @Mr.Wizard

Comment: It's OK now as the question will not become invalid if that link is broken, which was my primary concern.  However an even simpler example is always nice, and may increase the speed or likelihood of receiving an answer.

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. One weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Comment: I'm afraid not. They are very slow and are not applicable in general cases @rhermans

Answer (score 2):

**small answer:**

Instead of

```
Collect[rr + rr^(1 + n) + rr^3, rr]
(*rr^3 + rr (1 + rr^n)*)
```

use

```
Collect[rr + rr^(1 + n) + rr^3, rr^_] 
(*rr + rr^3 + rr^(1 + n)*)
```

**complete answer:**

Before using Numerator and Denominator  you have to transform `expr` in a rational form:

```
exprTog=Together[expr];
```

The denominator doesn't depend on rr

```
D[Denominator[exprT], rr] (* ==0 *)
```

and the numerator includes terms `rr^0 & rr^6`

```
cl = CoefficientList[ Numerator[exprT], rr];
Length[cl]
(*7*)

Simplify[First[cl] ]
(*512 (3 a - 2 h) H^3 (-2 G H (G + H) + 3 a (G^2 + G H + H^2)) ((g^2 - h^2) (2 g h (g + h) -3 a (g^2 + g h + h^2)) + (-2 g h (g^3 + 2 g^2 h + 2 g h^2 + h^3) + 3 a (g^4 + 2 g^3 h + g^2 h^2 + 2 g h^3 + h^4)) Cos[2 t]) Cos[tp]^2 Sec[t]*)

Simplify[Last[cl]]
(*9 a^2 G^2 h^3 H^5 (G +H) ((g^2 - h^2) (2 g h (g + h) - 
3 a (g^2 + g h + h^2)) + (-2 g h (g^3 + 2 g^2 h + 2 g h^2 + 
h^3) + 3 a (g^4 + 2 g^3 h + g^2 h^2 + 2 g h^3 + h^4)) Cos[2 t]) Cos[tp]^2 
(-2 - 6 Cos[2 (t - th)] + 15 Cos[2 (t - 2 th - tp)] + 
3 Cos[2 (t + tp)] + 6 Cos[2 (th + tp)])^2 Sec[t]*)
```

Comment: It helps, but not always. For example it doesn't return what I want for the expr presented in the link

Comment: "In the link" means huge `expr` of your question?

Comment: Yes it does ....

Comment: Could any one help me? expr is presented here. link is in the word here

Comment: Your last comment is unclear! What do you know about the structure of your expression, is it rational ?

Comment: Together takes a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

Since `Collect` seems to be able to give you a fraction that is almost on the form you want, I'll substitute an example fraction here:

```
frac = (c[1]+rr^2 (2 rr^4+3 rr^6+4 rr^8+5 rr^10) c[2]-
   rr^3 (2 rr^6+3 rr^9+4 rr^12+5 rr^15) c[3])/
 (d[1]+rr^7 (2 rr^4+3 rr^6+4 rr^8+5 rr^10) d[2]-
   rr^11 (2 rr^6+3 rr^9+4 rr^12+5 rr^15) d[3])
```

You can treat the numerator and denominators as polynomials in `rr`:

```
num = Numerator[frac];
den = Denominator[frac];
newfrac = With[{cl1 = CoefficientList[num, rr], cl2 = CoefficientList[den, rr]},
  (cl1.rr^Range[0,Length[cl1]-1])/(cl2.rr^Range[0,Length[cl2]-1])
]
```

> `(c[1]+2 rr^6 c[2]+3 rr^8 c[2]+4 rr^10 c[2]+rr^12 (5 c[2]-3 c[3])-2 rr^9 c[3]-4 rr^15 c[3]-5 rr^18 c[3])/(d[1]+2 rr^11 d[2]+3 rr^13 d[2]+4 rr^15 d[2]+rr^17 (5 d[2]-2 d[3])-3 rr^20 d[3]-4 rr^23 d[3]-5 rr^26 d[3])`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following hack which I invented when working with extremely large expressions containing millions of terms in many vars. The hack works much better and faster than Collect, when one needs to collect terms to the given powers of specific vars. Of course, as was suggested by Marius Ladegård Meyer your need to work with numerator and denominator separately

The numerator:

```
FromCoefficientRules[
 Normal[Association @@ (CoefficientRules[
     Expand[Numerator[Together[expr]]], {rr}])], {rr}]
```

And similarly for denominator.

Note, that instead of just single rr, you have possibility to collect using many vars. And the most important thing is that the collection is extremely fast.

**Edit 1**

As Daniel Lichtblau noted the Normal[Association @@ is superfluous. Therefore fast collection of coefficients of variables var1,var2,... of the polynomial poly can be obtained  with

FromCoefficientRules[
     CoefficientRules[poly, {var1,var2,...}], {var1,var2,...}]

Comment: It is very very slow indeed.

Comment: For the expression your gave in the question (I didn't try the file) the collection method based on Association Key handling took few seconds on 10 year old laptop. Most of time, of course, being spend inside  Together and Expand. I will be surprised (and very happy as well) if somebody will suggest a faster method.

Comment: I used your code, after 10 minutes, my laptop confused

Comment: It takes 1.34251 seconds for the numerator on Mathematica version 10.3, 2008 year laptop running old Linux OS. The leaf count of the result is 162982. You have to split the code into the pieces to find the problem. I only can repeat that using the Association approach I was able to Collect terms for expressions with millions of terms and typical leaf count of the collected result  of hundreds of millions (intermediate results taking more than 100Gb RAM). With system Collect and pattern matching  approach the transformation  would hardly be possible.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Dear Daniel, if you programmed FromCoefficientRules[], would it be possible to extend the command to accept the Association as an argument?

Comment: I did not actually implement that function.

Comment: It takes alot of time because Together works very slowly